# Is it possible to make constructor property assigment list like this make shorter?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Is it possible to avoid "this" assignment list and somehow "spread" all the args named in constructor?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
        this.arg3 = arg3;
        this.arg4 = arg4;
        this.arg5 = arg5;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are the property names always like `arg{N}`?

Comment: no matter on names - just to somehow spread args to its same or simmilar this.properties

Comment: How about passing an object as the constructor parameter instead of separate arguments?

Comment: Barmar - show me please what you had on mind

Comment: `new MyClass({ arg1: 1, arg2: "foo", ...})`? Then you can use `Object.assign()` in the constructor.

Comment: Or go with your original arguments, and use `Object.assign(this, {arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5});`

Comment: I'm not sure which comment you're linking to. But he never said it changes dynamically, just that it can change over time. When you change it, you change the `Object.assign` line accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of keys an iterate the arguments.

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(...args) {
        var keys = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5']
        keys.forEach((k, i) => this[k] = args[i]);
    }
}

var instance = new MyClass('a', 'b');

console.log(instance);
```

Comment: This is probably what @NenadVracar was thinking of.

Comment: Might be better to iterate over `keys`, then you'll simply ignore any extra args.

Comment: Barnar - write as a comment so I could flag it as correct answer